# Display array of errors in with $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, session-variables

I made an array of my errors messages and I want to display each of them when necessary only

```
  $_SESSION['error']=[
        'error_clientName' => 'Le nom du client doit comporter au moins 2 caractères',
        'error_color' => 'La couleur doit être au format hexadécimal',
        'error_nav' => 'Merci de choisir une couleur de de barre de navigation',
        'error_download' => 'Une erreur est survenue durant le téléchargement',
        'error_logo' => 'Le fichier doit être une image png, jpg ou svg',
        'error_mockup' => 'Le fichier doit être une image en jpg',
        'error_empty_logo' => 'Merci de choisir un logo',
        'error_empty' => 'Merci de remplir tous les champs',
    ];

   $errors=$_SESSION[ 'error' ];
```

I don't know how to handle it to display messages, first I tried this but it dislays all messages, logical ...

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo implode('<br>', $_SESSION['error']);
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

Then I tried a loop to go through my array, but it does not work :

```
foreach ($errors as $error){
    echo implode('<br>', $error);
    unset ($error);
}
```

If you have any tips ? thx :)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you see an error? Or do you see nothing?

Comment: And what's inside `$errors` in your first part of code? Because you overwrite the previous assignment there

Comment: Why would you store a bunch of errors you don't want to show in sessions? Create a proper error class that contains all messages and make some methods to get specific messages.

Comment: The If construction works but displays all errors, when I want to display only the relevant ones. The loop displays the following errors "Undefined variable: errors and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" . I did not know how to put $_SESSION[ 'error' ] in the loop so I put my  $_SESSION[ 'error' ] into $errors, I made a mistake in my previous message ;
 @jrswgtr

Comment: What do you mean by: _I want to display only the relevant ones_?

Comment: If you only want to display for instance the error for `error_color` you can `echo $_SESSION['error']['error_color'];`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display each of them in a list, one per line etc.

Can't you just wrap it with an `<ul> > <li>` and handle the line breaks through CSS?

Else you should be able to just do a...

```
foreach ($errors as $error){
    echo "{$error}<br>"
}
```

**EDIT: 12th of September, 2020**

Ohhh right, i see now that i misread your problem!

How exactly do you determine which one you need?

Based on your own examples it seems you're trying to show all messages at once with that `implode('<br>', $arr)` solution

And to make sure i understand correctly, this is a static list right? and you want to retrieve each message only when needed?

Or is the array of errors dynamically added to the list from e.g. form validation errors? (or any other source) and then you need to display them when needed only?

Still not 100% if i understood your issue correctly, but here are a couple of examples.

**Example #1**

```
/**
 * Function error_message
 * 
 * @param $message_id
 *
 * @return string
 */
function error_message($message_id) {
    $errors = [
       'error_clientName' => 'Le nom du client doit comporter au moins 2 caractères',
       'error_color' => 'La couleur doit être au format hexadécimal',
       'error_nav' => 'Merci de choisir une couleur de de barre de navigation',
       'error_download' => 'Une erreur est survenue durant le téléchargement',
       'error_logo' => 'Le fichier doit être une image png, jpg ou svg',
       'error_mockup' => 'Le fichier doit être une image en jpg',
       'error_empty_logo' => 'Merci de choisir un logo',
       'error_empty' => 'Merci de remplir tous les champs',
    ];
    
    return isset($errors[ $message_id ]) ? $errors[ $message_id ] : '' ;
}

/**
 * Usage
 */
echo error_message('error_clientName');
```

**Example #2:** or perhaps split them into categories within your error array if you want to display a group of them at a specific place.

```
$errors = [
    ['error_category_1'] => [
        'error_clientName' => 'Le nom du client doit comporter au moins 2 caractères',
        'error_color' => 'La couleur doit être au format hexadécimal',
        'error_nav' => 'Merci de choisir une couleur de de barre de navigation',
    ],
    ['error_category_2'] => [
        'error_download' => 'Une erreur est survenue durant le téléchargement',
        'error_logo' => 'Le fichier doit être une image png, jpg ou svg',
    ],
    ['error_category_3'] => [
        'error_mockup' => 'Le fichier doit être une image en jpg',
        'error_empty_logo' => 'Merci de choisir un logo',
        'error_empty' => 'Merci de remplir tous les champs',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I am afrid this loop does not work, I already tried

Answer (score 0):

You will have to know which error codes are "relevant" to only display the relevant ones.

Then loop trough the codes and check if the message exists in the session before displaying it.

```php
$relevantErrorCodes = ['error_clientName', 'error_empty_logo'];

foreach($relevantErrorCodes as $errorCode) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['error']) && isset($_SESSION['error'][$errorCode])) {
        echo $_SESSION['error'][$errorCode] . '<br />';
    }
}
```